# Unable to find index for $geoNear query even using index

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using 3.6.5(mongodb) and trying to get documents near specified location like [-10, 20]...

When I tried get request "http://localhost:3030/ninjas?lng=-80&lat=20" it returns "unable to find index for $geoNear query"

I tried adding index(), changing query and searching official document but, failed.

please help!

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/gpsTest")
    .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB...'))
    .catch(err => console.error(('Could not connect to MongoDB...\n'), err))


const NinjaSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
    },
    rank: {
        type: String,
    },
    available: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    geometry: {
        type: {
            type: String,
            default: "Point",
            index: '2dsphere'
        },
        coordinates: {
            type: [Number]
        }
    }
})
NinjaSchema.index({geometry: '2dsphere'});

const Ninja = mongoose.model('ninja', NinjaSchema);

app.post('/ninjas', (req, res) => {
    Ninja.create(req.body).then(ninja => {
        res.send(ninja);
    })
})

app.get('/ninjas', (req, res) => {
    Ninja.find({}).where('location').nearSphere({center: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates : [parseFloat(req.query.lng), parseFloat(req.query.lat)],
        spherical: true
    }}
    ).then(ninjas => {
        res.send(ninjas);
    });
})
app.listen(3030, () => {
    console.log(`listening port: 3030`);
})
```

This one is for post request.

> {     "name": "test",     "rank": "red belt",     "available": true,
>     "geometry" : {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-80, 27]} }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of typo...
Should change

> Ninja.find({}).where('location').nearSphere({center: {...

to

> Ninja.find({}).where('geometry').nearSphere({center: {...